# If block is never executed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a beginner with scripts, why doesn't it work? it always goes to C1 even when the condition is true

```
function provaIf() {
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   if(spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate()  == 1){
   spreadsheet.getRange('B1').activate(); }
   else {
   spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range` object is different from "value". Try [`Range.getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())

```
  if(spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue()  == 1){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly fine. 
What your code does is verifying that 'A1' is activated and equals 1.
What [`activate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate%28%29) does is like if you click on the cell or the range. It does not pick the values of the cell/range.
So if you want your code to only check if 'A1' = 1 you should use **[TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140063/if-block-is-never-executed?answertab=votes#answer-59140298)**'s answer.

```
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue()  == 1
```

With the [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) function you are actually getting the value inside of the cell/range.